# Plot repeated hours of multi-days vs some data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a CSV file containing five columns year, day number, hour, S, and d.
I want to plot hours versus S and d columns. Where the hour column is as
0,1,2,.....,23,0,1,...,23 .. etc

I write the following command to do it

```
import pandas as pd
fig = pd.read_csv('figt.csv')
x = [str(x) for x in fig.hr]
y1 = fig.kp_index
y2 = fig.bz
fo=8

figure, axs = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (10, 7),sharex=True)

axs[1].bar(range(len(x)), y1,width=0.5)
axs[1].set_ylabel("S index",fontsize=fo)
axs[1].set_yticks((0, 50, 100))

axs[0].plot(range(len(x)), y2)
axs[0].set_ylabel("B",fontsize=fo)
axs[0].set_yticks((-10, 0, 10))
```

but the X-axis appears from 0 to 175, as

[image: test]

I want the X-axis appears by hours as

0, 12, 23,  0, 12, 23, 0, 12, 23 ....

OR days as

28-Oct, 29-Oct, 31-Oct, 1-Nov, ....

until the data ended.

I tried also to convert the day number to the date and then plot it, but I can not succeed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Maybe this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751613/how-to-make-a-plot-by-repeating-strings-on-x-axis-in-matplotlib). Basically create dummy `x` axis, maybe create a list like `[0]+['' for _ in range(11)]+[12]+['' for _ in range(11)] +[23]` where simply you show empty string for the values you don't want to show and repeat the same list by the number of days.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now if I want to convert X axis to days for example
28-Oct, 29-Oct, 31-Oct, 1-Nov, .... etc. How I can do that?